# Can you identify this truck with spikey wheels?

Tags: set-identification

[image: LEGOs]

I would like to know what set this partially put-together truck belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

[Legends of Chima 70004-1: Wakz' Pack Tracker](https://brickset.com/sets/70004-1/Wakz-Pack-Tracker)

[image: set image]